# Go to specific zoom values on mouse wheel movements in openlayers

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-5

I have created a map using openlayers and have created an array of zoom values which are in decimals (for ex. [0.2, 1.13, 2.15, 3.45, 4.23, 5.14]. Now when I use mouse wheel to zoom in or zoom out of the map the zoom values changes in integer (for ex. 1 to 2 or 1 to 0). I want the zoom values to change to the values in the array. How can I achieve this?

Here's my map code:

```
let map = new Map({
        controls: [],
        interactions: defaults({mouseWheelZoom: false}).extend([
            new MouseWheelZoom({
              constrainResolution: true
            })
          ]),
        target: null,
        layers: [
            layer,
        ],
        view: view,
        keyboardEventTarget: setKeyboardInteractions ? document : null,
        loadTilesWhileAnimating: true,
        loadTilesWhileInteracting: true
    });
```

I have implemented my own Increment and decrement zoom level functions:

```
incrementZoomLevel = () => {
        let index = Math.floor(zoom); //Get current zoom level
        if(index != ZValues.length - 1) { //ZValues is my decimal zoom array
             view.setZoom(ZValues[index + 1]);
         }
    }

decrementZoomLevel = () => {
        let index = Math.floor(zoom);
        if(index != 0) {
            view.setZoom(ZValues[index - 1]);
        }
    }
```

So if I can find any scroll event listeners of openlayers then I can call these functions and change the values but I'm not able to find any such listener.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom view where the resolutions of the zoom levels are based on the fractional values of a standard view

```
let defaultView = new View();

zooms = [0.2, 1.13, 2.15, 3.45, 4.23, 5.14];

let resolutions = zooms.map(function(zoom) {
  return defaultView.getResolutionForZoom(zoom);
});

let customView = new View({resolutions: resolutions})
```

Are you using OpenLayers 5?  In OpenLayers 6 the `constrainResolution` option must be set in the view, not in the interactions.

Comment: I'm using OpenLayers 5. I will try this solution.

Comment: I tried making the new View for my map based on the new resolutions but still it is zooming to [0, 1, 2, 3..] and not the decimal levels. Do I have to change the resolutions in the layers also?

Comment: It will use only integer levels.  The new integer levels should be at the same resolutions as the decimal levels in the old view, so have the effect you wanted.

Comment: I added the resolutions in the layer also and now it is zooming correctly but now the image is cropped. So basically it zooms the image not as a whole but cropping the remaining part. So my earlier solution is working for normal zoom as I'm switching to the decimal levels on the zoom button click as I have made my own buttons. But the same thing is not working when I scroll as it switches to the integer zoom level. If I can get any event listeners of openlayers on scroll then it may help.

Comment: I have added my increment and decrement Zoom level functions also in the question. Please check.

Comment: If you have a tile layer the tiles will always be served at the tile grid resolutions, they do not need to match the view resolutions (unless you have a custom source with those resolutions?).  Or are you using WMS at fixed resolutions?

Comment: I have a custom source for the tiles to be served.

Comment: For now I have solved this issue. I have added a 'moveend' listener and whenever the zoom the becoming integer, I'm changing it to the correct decimal value by using my array. This is sort of a temp fix. I was not able to find any listener specific to mouse scroll.